# jquery not changing classes for list items, how to fix that?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

To have a common navigator for multiple classes, I have kept that in a separate HTML file and trying to import that in the home page using jquery.

```
 <!-- ======= Header ======= --><!-- End Header -->
  <div id="header-part"></div>

 <div id="footer-part"></div>
```

And replaced the div element using jquery.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("#header-part").load("include_files/header.html");
      $("#footer-part").load("include_files/footer.html");
      $("#courses-tab").addClass("active");
      $("#pricing-tab").removeClass("active");
    </script>
```

The pages are loading correctly but to change the active tab on the header, I added IDs to the individual list items and tried to activate them as the above last two lines where I am adding the class.

But the class add and remove part not working.

My repo: [link](https://github.com/uday1kiran/uday1kiran.github.io)

Comment: Probably the add and remove class calls happen before the ext files loading. You should use promises

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: I searched the entire code I don't see `courses-tab` and `pricing-tab`

Comment: @DickensAS - Oh wow. And yeah, sure enough, the only place they exist is the code above in `index.html`. @ udaykiran - Where do these elements magically come from? They aren't in https://github.com/uday1kiran/uday1kiran.github.io/blob/master/include_files/header.html, for instance.

Comment: Sorry the include folder not synced. I did it.

Comment: Locally it is running as you sugested, but in the github hosting, it stuck in the loading only

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [load method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) has a callback function, which

> is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been
> performed

```
$("#header-part").load( "include_files/header.html", function() {
    $("#courses-tab").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Huh, I thought ~8k users could see deleted answers. We've been down this road... :-)

Comment: Have no idea what are you talking about @T.J.Crowder

Comment: You can't see the deleted answer to this question? (Irritatingly, the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) doesn't say when that privilege kicks in, but I thought it kicked in no later than 5k.) Basically: I posted that answer, the OP said it didn't work. :-| (Since the OP's question is [at best] incomplete there's no much point in trying to answer it.)

Comment: No, cannot see deleted posts. But, obviously, his code is wrong and the above is the solution - in case he has other issues, than he should post another question.

Comment: Huh, must be a 10k privilege.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder FY https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges - looks like it is 10k

Comment: @freedomn-m - Thanks. I clicked the wrong side of that two-column layout of links. :-)